# How to use a fixed font in Polymer's paper-textarea?

Tags: polymer

When using the following Polymer component:

```
<paper-textarea value="test"></paper-textarea>
```

I did not find any way to change its font to a fixed font. (for code entry)

I tried the following styling, but just the color was actually applied:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-input-container-input-color: blue;
    /* the following lines do not work... */
    --paper-input-font-family: monospace;
    --iron-autogrow-textarea: {
      font-family: monospace;
    };
  }
</style>
```

Any one knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

paper-textarea uses iron-autogrow-textarea.
This should work (not tried myself)

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --iron-autogrow-textarea: {
      font-family: monospace !important;
    };
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not... Do you think that I need a specific version of Polymer, webcomponents or paper-input for this to work?

Comment: You aren't using the most recent version?

Comment: I tried it myself. I had to add `!important` to make it work. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: always disturbing to have to use !important, but it does work! thanks gunter!

Comment: I don't know another way to increase selectivity because the selector is in the paper-textarea. This is why I think it should be reported as bug.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use `!important`. This will work in Polymer 2.0:

```css
paper-textarea {
  --iron-autogrow-textarea: {
    font-family: monospace;
  };
}
```